# Infinite loop when updating JPanel's graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

So, I am drawing a graphic in a `JPanel` object using `Grahics2D`.
The `JPanel` is placed in a `JScrollPane` for the cases when my graphic is bigger than the window.
But after I draw my graphic the `JPanel`'s size does not change and I cannot scroll to see the rest of my graphic, so I locate the lowest and most left points and set the size manually in the method that does the drawing (method is called `drawTrack()`).
When I switch windows or do something else that makes the JPanel to be drawn again, my graphic disappears, so I rewrote `paint()`, `repaint()`, `validate()`, `invalidate()` methods and in there I invoke the `drawTrack()` method to draw my graphic on every possible case of redrawing the JPanel.
The problem is that when the `JPanel` invokes one of the methods that do the redrawing I invoke `drawTrack()` in them, which after redrawing my graphic sets the size manually so that I can scroll the `JScrollPane` and see my whole graphic. But when I invoke `setSize()` method on the JPanel that makes it to be redrawn again, which means to invoke `drawTrack()` and so on and so on.
The scroll bars appear because the size is correct but it creates an infinite loop that redraws my graphic over and over. And if I don't invoke the `setSize()` method my `JPanel` gets default size so it can fit in the `JScrollPane`'s viewport and thus I cannot scroll it to see my graphic.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please provide a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)? Otherwise I don't think that we can help you.

Comment: Please see example of what I mean and also an example of an SSCCE below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you resize a JPanel you stimulate a repaint, and so if you change the size in a paint or paintComponent method or a method called in either of these methods, it makes sense to me that you are at risk of causing an infinite loop.

Solution: Don't resize anything in a paint or paintComponent method.  That method is just for painting and nothing else. Instead if you want to set the size of your JPanel, override its getPreferredSize() method.

Here's a "colorful" example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImageReSize extends JPanel {
   private static final int INIT_WIDTH = 400;
   private static final int MAX_WIDTH = 1200;

   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
   protected static final int WIDTH_STEP = 5;
   private int width = INIT_WIDTH;
   private int height = INIT_WIDTH;
   private boolean growing = true;

   public ImageReSize() {
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (growing && width < MAX_WIDTH) {
               width += WIDTH_STEP;
               height += WIDTH_STEP;
            } else {
               growing = false;
            }

            if (!growing && width > INIT_WIDTH) {
               width -= WIDTH_STEP;
               height -= WIDTH_STEP;
            } else {
               growing = true;
            }
            // get the parent container which is the scrollpane's viewport
            JComponent parent = (JComponent)getParent();
            parent.revalidate(); // let it relayout the changed size JPanel
            parent.repaint();  // and repaint all
         }
      }).start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
      float x = (float)width / 10;
      float y = (float)height / 10;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(x, 0, Color.green, 0, y, Color.black, true));
      g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
      g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.blue, x, y, Color.red, true));
      g2.fillOval(0, 0, width, height);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(width, height);
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      ImageReSize imageReSize = new ImageReSize();
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ImageReSize");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(imageReSize));
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> so I rewrote paint(), repaint(), validate(), invalidate() methods and in there I invoke the drawTrack() method

This is unnecessary. The custom painting code should only ever be invoked from the paintComponent() method.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar problem: JPanel's paintComponent method called other "methods", that involved changes in Graphics and therefore called for another paintComponent loop.

I haven't found a structural way to move these "methods" outside paintComponent, but found the following solution: surround these "methods" with if clause and break the loop with a boolean flag:

```
boolean flag;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    if (flag) {
        gModify(); // Method that modifies Graphics g object and calls another paintComponent loop.
        flag = !flag; // True to false - miss gModify() in the second paintComponent entry to break the loop.
    } else {
        flag = !flag; // False to true - allow gModify() after second  paintComponent entry.
    }

}
```